# \widowpenalty: the negative infinite penalty

Tags: winedt, widows-orphans

I would like to know how do I make the MWE below work. How do I get know that

> \widowpenalty

has been set to -infinite ?

Also, I would like to ask what is the orphan penalty starting with `\g` called in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\widowpenalty=-10000

\begin{document}
\widowpenalty=-10000
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

222222222222222222222222222222222

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A penalty `\widowpenalty` is added to the main vertical list only when TeX is contributing a multiline paragraph, between the last two lines.

If a paragraph has only one line, it can generate neither a widow nor an orphan line.

The following document will end up with two pages, because it consists of a three-line paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\widowpenalty=-10000

\begin{document}

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
222222222222222222222222222222222\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `\clubpenalty` and `\widowpenalty` ? Thank you.

Comment: @user2925716 `\clubpenalty` is inserted between the *first* two lines of a multiline paragraph. A two-line paragraph gets both.

Comment: (Complement to [@egreg’s comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516541/widowpenalty-the-negative-infinite-penalty#comment1306200_516544).)  More precisely, in a two-line paragraph a *single* penalty, equal to the sum of `\clubpenalty` and `\widowpenalty`, is inserted between the lines.  For example, try `{\widowpenalty = -10000 \clubpenalty 5000 \par}`.